# unusual white space on either side of css grid

Tags: css

I have my margin and padding set to zero, but for some reason there is still about 200px of white space on each side of my css grid. When I place the css inside style tags on the .html document the content stretches the entire main axis, as it should. When I put the same exact css code in a .css file, the white space appears. Please help!

CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  height: 100vh;

}

.box1 {
  color: #dddddd;
background-color: #460000;

}

.box2 {

  background-image: url("img/brick-bg-image.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked to your stylesheet in you HTML file? i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`?

Comment: there is something going around. I genuinely thought the same and was wondering why would you get a downvote. I will give you a vote up as this seems to be the first thing to ask in that situation.

Comment: Thank you @MitkoDelibaltov thought I was missing something

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your Stylesheet added in  `<head>`  element looking like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

In case it is loaded you can open it in new window in the browser to check how it looks. Sometimes the path is incorrect or some other issue. (I do this sometimes to check my style if it is loaded correctly).

In case it is loaded and opening in new tab you may want to check the content. Sometimes the browser caches the css file and you need to hard-refresh with CTRL+F5 to clear the cache.

Hope this would help you. I don't see a reason if it works added in style to not work when added with css file.

Comment: I linked the style sheet because the background and columns are present. I looked in the developer tools and there seems to be a border and padding around the .container div, however I hardcoded the margin and padding on the .container div.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem:

I was using the bootstrap.css style sheet. That was overriding the inline styles.